# Solve following sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}2^{-n}}{n} $

I am very unsure how to evaluate this, as the sign changes I would separate them in two series, one positive and one negative   $$\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2)^{2n-1}}$$ and $$-\frac{1}{(2n)(2)^{2n}}$$

However I can't evaluate them right.

Comment: By "Solve", do you mean you want to evaluate them?

Comment: integrate the geometric series

Comment: In case of infinite series, breaking the series is not the right way to go. That may result in you getting a false result. In fact, first test whether the series is even convergent or not using alternating series test.

Answer (score 5):

We re-write this sum to $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)(-2)^{-n}}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{-1}{(-2)^n \cdot n}$$

For $-1 \le x < 1$, define $$f(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$$

We have $$f'(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1} = \frac{1}{1-x}$$

This gives $$f(x)=- \ln (1-x)+C$$

It is clear that $C=0$.

Therefore, we have $$f(x)=-\ln (1-x)$$
Plugging $x=-\frac{1}{2}$, we have $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(-2)^n \cdot n} = f(-\frac{1}{2}) = -\ln (\frac{3}{2})$$

Our desired answer is $$-f(-\frac{1}{2})=\ln (\frac{3}{2})$$

Comment: You do need to mention that the result $f(x)=-\ln(1-x)$ is valid iff $-1\leq x\lt 1$

Answer (score 1):

Begin with:

$1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + \cdots = \dfrac{1}{1+x} = \sum_{n=0}(-1)^nx^n$ (Why is this true?)

Notice you have a term $n$ in the denominator. (So, what to do? Integrate the power series?)

So you have $\ln(1+x) = \sum_{n=0} (-1)^n \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$, with the correct interval of convergence. (Why?)

I want to make the summation 'appear' similar to the one you gave, so I would change the index so that

$\sum_{n=1}(-1)^{n-1}\dfrac{x^n}{n} $. The only thing left is to substitute $x = \dfrac{1}{2}$. (Confirm if 1/2 is within the interval of convergence of this power series, if yes then this series will converge.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k=\frac1{1-x}.$$

Then integrating,

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}=\ln(1-x).$$

$x$ may be negative.

Answer (score 1):

**Indirect and contrived**:

As is not so well-known, the logarithm can be defined as

$$\log(t)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n(t^{1/n}-1).$$

Then with $t=1+2^{-1}$, we develop $n((1+2^{-1})^{1/n}-1)$ using the generalized binomial formula and get

$$n\left(
1+\frac1n2^{-1}+\frac1n\left(\frac1n-1\right)\frac{2^{-2}}2+
\frac1n\left(\frac1n-1\right)\left(\frac1n-2\right)\frac{2^{-3}}{3!}+
\frac1n\left(\frac1n-1\right)\left(\frac1n-2\right)\left(\frac1n-3\right)\frac{2^{-4}}{4!}+\cdots-1
\right)=$$

$$2^{-1}+\left(\frac1n-1\right)\frac{2^{-2}}2+\left(\frac1n-1\right)\left(\frac1n-2\right)\frac{2^{-3}}{3!}+\left(\frac1n-1\right)\left(\frac1n-2\right)\left(\frac1n-3\right)\frac{2^{-4}}{4!}+\cdots\to$$

$$2^{-1}-\frac{2^{-2}}2+\frac{2^{-3}}{3}-\frac{2^{-4}}{4}+\cdots=\log(1.5)$$ when $n$ goes to $\infty$.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the expansion of the series $\ln(1+x)$

$\ln(1+x)=x-x^2/2+x^3/3-x^4/4+\cdots$$

Put $x=1/2=0.5$

Belongs in the Radius of Convergence as it is less than 1

$\ln(1.5)=0.5-0.5^2/2+0.5^3/3-\cdots$$

Which is the above-mentioned series